# Karma: project using requirejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm newbie using Karma+Jasmine and I'm working in a project which uses requirejs to load JavaScript modules. When I run Karma it shown the following error:

```
C:\node\myproject
λ node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket JYDsGfVNWZpOj3qrK4jc with id 50580579
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7) ERROR
  Uncaught object
  at C:/node/myproject/public/js/vendor/requirejs/require.js:8
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 ERROR (0.019 secs / 0.017 secs)
```

Anybody can help me?
Thank you.

Comment: this seems like a problem with the code being tested. can you post source and the test?